# How can I migrate the Journal from ActiveMQ Artemis 1.5.6 to 2.7.0?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I would like to migrate my (embedded) ActiveMQ Artemis from 1.5.6 to 2.7.0 but on starts I get an error about journal incompatibility.

```
2019-05-09 17:10:08,762 main            org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server  ERROR AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is using old journal data, export your data and import at the correct version
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.persistence.impl.journal.AbstractJournalStorageManager.loadMessageJournal(AbstractJournalStorageManager.java:912)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.loadJournals(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2980)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.initialisePart2(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2690)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.LiveOnlyActivation.run(LiveOnlyActivation.java:72)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.internalStart(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:564)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.start(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:501)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:376)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS.start(EmbeddedJMS.java:131)
```

How can I migrate the messages without losing data?

I found the change which introduces the new format (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1009) but I didn't find information how to migrate, or how to use the old format.

The 2.7.0 server I start the following way:

```java
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationImpl();
configuration.setJMXManagementEnabled(false);

configuration.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
configuration.setBindingsDirectory(persistenceLocation + "bindings");
configuration.setJournalDirectory(persistenceLocation + "journal");
configuration.setPagingDirectory(persistenceLocation + "paging");
configuration.setLargeMessagesDirectory(persistenceLocation + "largemessages");

configuration.addAddressesSetting("#", new AddressSettings().setAutoCreateJmsQueues(false).setAutoDeleteJmsQueues(false));
configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration("in-vm", "vm://0");
configuration.addAcceptorConfiguration("tcp","tcp://" +host+  ":" + port + "?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.");

configuration.setSecurityEnabled(true);
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
roles.add(new Role(PRODUCER, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
roles.add(new Role(CONSUMER, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
configuration.putSecurityRoles("#", roles);

JMSQueueConfigurationImpl queueConfig = new JMSQueueConfigurationImpl();
queueConfig.setDurable(true);
queueConfig.setName("Provisioning");

JMSConfiguration jmsConfig = new JMSConfigurationImpl();
jmsConfig.getQueueConfigurations().add(queueConfig);

SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration();
securityConfiguration.addUser(user, password);
securityConfiguration.addRole(user, PRODUCER);
securityConfiguration.addRole(user, CONSUMER);
securityConfiguration.setDefaultUser(user);

ActiveMQSecurityManager securityManager = new ActiveMQJAASSecurityManager(InVMLoginModule.class.getName(),
                        securityConfiguration);
// Start server
EmbeddedJMS server = new EmbeddedJMS();
server.setJmsConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
server.setConfiguration(configuration);
server.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
server.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Artemis [`data`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/data-tools.html) tools to export and import your journal.

1. Navigate to the `bin` directory of your Artemis 1.5.6 instance.
2. Export the journal data: `./artemis data exp > /tmp/export.xml`
3. Navigate to the `bin` directory of your Artemis 2.7.0 instance.
4. Start the broker: `./artemis run`
5. Import the 1.5.6 journal data: `./artemis data imp --input /tmp/export.xml`

The import requires a running broker and by default it will try to connect to `localhost:61616`. However, you can use the `--host` and `--port` switches to change that if necessary.

If you'd rather work directly with the underlying Java rather than the command-line tools, you can do something like this to export:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.tools.xml.XmlDataExporter;
...
ByteArrayOutputStream xmlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
XmlDataExporter xmlDataExporter = new XmlDataExporter();
xmlDataExporter.process(xmlOutputStream, "BindingsDirectory", "JournalDirectory", "PagingDirectory", "LargeMessagesDirectory");
System.out.print(new String(xmlOutputStream.toByteArray()));
```

This needs to be run by the version native to the journal you're exporting so, for example, if you want to export a journal from version 1.5.6 then these classes must come from the 1.5.6 jars as that's the version that can properly read the journal.

To import, you can run something like this:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.tools.xml.XmlDataImporter;
...
ByteArrayInputStream xmlInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlOutputStream.toByteArray());
XmlDataImporter xmlDataImporter = new XmlDataImporter();
xmlDataImporter.validate(xmlInputStream);
xmlInputStream.reset();
xmlDataImporter.process(xmlInputStream, session);
```

Here the `session` points to the broker instance where you want to import the data.

You can see many working examples of this in the [ActiveMQ Artemis test-suite](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/tests/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/tests/integration/persistence/XmlImportExportTest.java).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. 
We ship the broker embedded in our software, that means we would need our customer to install the broker in two versions, and then run the data tools. Many manual steps which are not the best for the UX. I would prefer to handle the migration in our code such that the customer can just install the new software.
Any experience doing the data migration in java?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. If the answer is helpful please vote it up. If it's correct please mark it as such. This will help other users in the future who have the same question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that brought me future. I manage to export from 1.5.6. and importing into a 1.5.6 system. But If I try to import into 2.7.0 it fails.  

Do I have to use the 1.5.6 or 2.7.0 for importing into a 2.7.0 server?  
I tried both, the 2.7.0 fails on validation:  
`
ERROR:  'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 110; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'binding'. One of '{address-binding, queue-binding}' is expected.'`  
The 1.5.6 client catches in a infinite loop in trying to connect/send to the JMS server.

Comment: I see now in the code where XML validation was added to the 2.x importer which means the 1.5.6 export won't validate. You should be able to use the 1.5.6 importer since 2.x should be backwards compatible. Are you getting an exception when you run the 1.5.6 importer?

Comment: No I don't get any error. It get stuck in a loop, and I think it is in the netty part trying to connect to the server. I put the code I use to start the server to the original question, maybe there is something wrong there. Or maybe with the "jms.queue" prefixing?

Comment: Hard to say without more details. Are you pointing the importer to the right host:port?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Else it gives a different error. And as said, if I use the 1.5.6 as server it works perfectly. I will let it rest for know, and try later again. Thanks again for your help.